# How to create group header in jasper report table using iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

Im trying to recreate a jrxml to be familiar in iReport. I already know how to create a simple table but this one's a bit complicated because of the grouping.

[image]

[image]

Could you tell me how to create another band called group header like the one shown in the screenshot? 
By the way i'm using iReport 5.6

Comment: And you are really sure you like to use jr:table component instead of working directly in the report detail band? Asking just because I see alot of unnecessary use of the jr:table that only tends to complicate the report development.  ... seems strange but jr:table is not the "normal" way to do tables in jasper report... : ). Furthermore please pass some relevant .jrxml code.

Comment: If with table check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425823/how-to-create-jasper-report-table-component-with-group-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the group in your **tabelDataSet**

```
<subDataset name="tableDataSet" uuid="c72d8dbd-d63e-411b-862d-a0d6e1e25d37">
   ....
  <group name="group1">
     <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{YourField}]]></groupExpression>
  </group>
</subDataset>
```

and you will find it magically in your table structure.

**EDIT: Added instructions for iReport:**

In iReport right click the groups in your tableDataset and select "Add group" (the screen shot is in Italian but "Aggiungi Gruppo" = "Add Group"

[image: iReport]

Comment: Does that mean there's no way to do it using iReport UI?

Comment: @user3714598 update post with instructions on how to add group in iReport